# How to change the color of a layer's icon?

Tags: inkscape

Layer's icons may have different colors, as e.g. in the “A4 leaflet 3-fold Roll” document template:

[image]

A layer's icon color is repeated in the status bar, too (near the layer's name):

[image]

But in the “Layers and Objects” dialog there is not an option for changing it, nor in the layer's context menu:

[image]

**How to change it?**

(Inkscape 1.2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also click on the colored line to the right of the layer/object name in the list, which opens a color picker dialog.

It's a small target, so it might be easy to miss while trying to click on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the layer, and in the “Object Properties” dialog (*Object → Object Properties...*) you will see its color:

[image]

Double-click on it, and you may select your desired color.